# make markers bounce from a list on google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a list of places in a text box in Google maps. When a person clicks on one of the places in the text box, I want the corresponding marker of that location in Google Maps to bounce. Any ideas on how I can make this work? Right now I am only able to make the marker bounce when I click on the marker itself.
Here is my code:

```js
var Points = [ {
    name: 'Duomo-Cathedral',
    lat: 43.7732,
    long: 11.2560,    
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
   
    }, {

    name: 'Orsanmichele-Church',  
    lat: 43.770947,
    long: 11.254981,    
    url: 'http://www.google.com' 
    }, {

    name: 'Ponte Vecchio-Old Bridge',  
    lat: 43.768350,
    long: 11.253323,   
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
    }, {

    name: 'Galleria delgi Uffizzi-Art Gallery',  
    lat: 43.768657,
    long: 11.255737,    
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
    }, {

    name: 'Santa Croce-Church',  
    lat: 43.768816,
    long: 11.262394, 
    add1: 'Piazza Santa Croce, 16', 
    add2: ' Florence, Italy 50122',
    phone: '+39 055 246 6105',   
    url: 'https://www.santacroceopera.it/'
    }, {

    name: 'Palazzo Vecchio-TownHall',  
    lat: 43.769670,
    long: 11.256075,    
    url: 'https://www.google.com'
    }, {

    name: 'Piazza della Signoria-OpenSquare',  
    lat: 43.769725,
    long: 11.255474,    
    url: 'http://www.google.com/'
    }, {

    name: 'Santa Maria Novella-Church',  
    lat: 43.774502,
    long: 11.249466,   
    url: 'https://www.google.com' 
    }, {

    name: 'Santa Maria Novella-TrainStation',  
    lat: 43.776261,
    long: 11.248737,    
    url: 'https://www.google.com'
    }, {

    name: 'San Lorenzo- ChurchMarket',  
    lat: 43.774858,
    long: 11.254584,    
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
    }
];


var markersArray = ko.observableArray([]);
Points.forEach(populateMarkersArray);

function populateMarkersArray(element) { //, index, array
    markersArray.push(element);
}

// Set up a google map
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 43.771341,lng: 11.256875}, 
    zoom: 16
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

function initialize() {
    Points.forEach(loadMarkers);

    var infowindow0 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(function() {
        infowindow0.close();
        marker0.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
        }

  // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
       
        marker0.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker0.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker0.setVisible(true);

         

 infowindow0.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow0.open(map, marker0);
    });
 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function loadMarkers(element) { //, index, array
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat,element.long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: element.name
    });
    loadInfoWindow(element, marker);
}

function loadInfoWindow(element, marker) {
    var contentString = '<div class="strong"><a href="' + element.url + '" target="_blank">' + element.name + '</a></div><div>' + element.add1 + '</div><div>' + element.add2 + '</div><div>'+ element.phone + '</div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        toggleBounce(marker);
    });
}

 function toggleBounce(marker) {
    if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}


function viewModel() {


  }
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Animations</title>
   <style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;  }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
.place-list {
  
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  max-height: 70%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 6px;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: white;
   border: 2px solid grey;
  opacity: 0.8;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
</style>       
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="place-list" data-bind="foreach: Points" >
        <li data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.marker" ></li>
    </ul> 

     
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
       
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.Com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCPgww-LhtxoQqq2zLI1_gOU1L2XayS-rE"> </script>
 <script src="js/lib/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help,
Max

Comment: You need to register a [DOM event listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) for each of your links. `google.maps.event.addDomListener();`

Comment: You could call your `toggleBounce()` function from the event listener but that would actually make it bounce on first click then stop the animation and so on. What I would do instead is: stop animation on all markers and set `google.maps.animation.BOUNCE` on the marker you are linking to.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your time and patience. Sounds like a good idea, but I'm having trouble implementing it. Could you please show me the full code of setting google.maps.animation.BOUNCE to see what I'm doing wrong? thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it is to use [Knockout.js data-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html). In particular, you can use [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) to display all your items as a list and apply functions to each of them. Then use [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) to execute functions attached to list items when a user clicks on it. An example of how to use it for list view of places in Google Maps with search function:

**HTML:**

```
<h4>Places</h4>
  <input type="text" id="my-Input" data-bind="textInput: filter" placeholder="Search for places..">
  <div class="scroll" id="my-UL">
      <ul data-bind="foreach: visiblePlaces">
         <li>
             <input data-bind="value: title, click: $parent.zoomToPlace, text: address" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-link" id="zoomTo">
         </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
/ ViewModel - provides list view of places, on click zooms map, shows the marker, infowindow, etc.
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.places = ko.observableArray(locations);
    self.address = ko.observable();
    self.title = ko.observable();
    self.id = ko.observable();
    this.filter = ko.observable();
    this.visiblePlaces = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.places().filter(function(place) {
            if (!self.filter() || place.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filter().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
                return place;
        });
    }, this);
    //Zooms to a selected marker and open infowindow
    self.zoomToPlace = function() {
        // Initialize the geocoder.
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        // Get the place.
        var address = this.address;
        var id = this.id;
        // Geocode the address/area entered to get the center. Then, center the map on it and zoom in
        geocoder.geocode({
            address: address,
        }, function(results, status) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(15);
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
        });
    };
}
var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

This will produce a list of places from an array (styles and array aren't shown in the code) and the corresponding marker will open an infowindow and bounce.

For full code, you can look it in my repo: https://github.com/DmitryGrechko/Neighborhood_Map